# The configuration of mysql server failed

Tags: mysql

I downloaded the latest version of mysql from the official site, during installation i didn't change setting and left it at default. I put 12345678 password.

[The erroe states configuration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxgAf.png)

EVERY INSTALLATION FAILS IN THE SAME STAGE  which is server configuration.

NOTE : mysql workbench is working fine but doesn't connect to server.

1- I removed every thing and tried with various editions.
2- I tried `mysqld --install` and `my sqld --intialize` but nothing happens.
2- I opened services.mac tried to start the service manually but it shows that error

[mysql service started and then stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCKr4.png)

I've seen many solutions working for other people but not working for me , Any advice?

Comment: Server is installed so you won't get much more from installer wizard. You need to check the regular server logs for more information.

Comment: it seems mysql installed but not started.. Check the data directory and my.cnf configuration.... if these things are good then perform below things: clear your datadir, initialize and start using mysqld

Comment: Thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález but this is a bit advanced for me in the meantime I think, However, the problem is solved by disabling the Anti-Virus and Firewall.

Comment: You're right @Adarsh mysqld was not able to start, I turned out to be a result of the firewall and antivirus of the windows.